# Trying to download a file from a button in UploadPanel. JS function InitializeRequest won't be triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to download a file if user clicks a button which is in UploadPanel. I'm following a forum page that was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081073/cannot-download-file-in-updatepanel).

When I run my ASP.NET page, I get alert 1 and 2 but not 3. What would be the problem? Here is my code:

**Default.aspx**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<script language="javascript">
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  alert(1);
  prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
  alert(2);
  function InitializeRequest(sender, args)
  {
    alert(3);
    if (sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id == "DownloadFile")
    {
      var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.src="GenerateFile.aspx";
      iframe.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
  }
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="DownloadFile" Text="Generate File" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be a problem if your Button Id is not matching because server and client id not same

you should use this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="DownloadFile" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Generate File" />
```